# Getting telemetry data from dji matrice 210 RTK to Raspberry pi with Rasbian

Tags: sdk, raspberry-pi, dji-sdk

I'm trying to get the telemetry data from the DJI matrice 210 RTK with a Raspberry pi3 through the OSDK.

I've followed the guide https://jamesthesken.github.io/dji-sdk-setup/ 
and manage to start serial communication but unable to receive data.

I've double-checked the possible reasons but none of them are the source of the problem.
This is the log I get:

STATUS/1 @ init, L65: ...Serial started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ sendData, L405: Port did not send
ERRORLOG/1 @sendData, L411:Open Protocol cmd send failed, send_len:0 packet_1en :19

ERRORLOG/1 @ getDroneVersion, L1418: Drone version not obtained! Please do not proceed.

I expected to run the telemetry sample and obtain the results.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

With the Raspberry Pi 3b you need to disable Bluetooth in order to make serial communication possible.

```
$ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @escardill above. I would suggest also just verifying that the tx pins are connected to rx pins, and vice versa, if you are using a USB to ttl adapter cable (the one DJI sells for $5).